# Deploy a Redis cluster with Docker

Tags: docker, kubernetes, redis

I need to create a Redis cluster using Docker (with Kubernetes afterwards) and didn't find any official documentation on that matter. Could I have guidance on that subject ?

I have the below yaml content but I am not sure if it follows the best practices:

```
version: '3'

networks:
  redis-cluster-compose:
    driver: bridge

services:
  redis-node-1:
    image: redis:latest
    ports:
      - 7000:7000
    networks:
      - redis-cluster-compose
    hostname: redis-node-1
    volumes:
      - ./7000:/redis
    command: redis-server /redis/redis.conf
  redis-node-2:
    image: redis:latest
    ports:
      - 7001:7001
    networks:
      - redis-cluster-compose
    hostname: redis-node-2
    volumes:
      - ./7001:/redis
    command: redis-server /redis/redis.conf

  redis-node-3:
    image: redis:latest
    ports:
      - 7002:7002
    networks:
      - redis-cluster-compose
    hostname: redis-node-3
    volumes:
      - ./7002:/redis
    command: redis-server /redis/redis.conf

  redis-node-4:
    image: redis:latest
    ports:
      - 7003:7003
    networks:
      - redis-cluster-compose
    hostname: redis-node-4
    volumes:
      - ./7003:/redis
    command: redis-server /redis/redis.conf

  redis-node-5:
    image: redis:latest
    ports:
      - 7004:7004
    networks:
      - redis-cluster-compose
    hostname: redis-node-5
    volumes:
      - ./7004:/redis
    command: redis-server /redis/redis.conf
  
  redis-node-6:
    image: redis:latest
    ports:
      - 7005:7005
    networks:
      - redis-cluster-compose
    hostname: redis-node-6
    volumes:
      - ./7005:/redis
    command: redis-server /redis/redis.conf
  
  redis-cluster-creator:
    image: redis:latest
    ports:
      - 6999:6999
    networks:
      - redis-cluster-compose
    command: redis-cli -p 7000 --cluster create redis-node-1:7000 redis-node-2:7001 redis-node-3:7002 redis-node-4:7003 redis-node-5:7004 redis-node-6:7005 --cluster-replicas 1 --cluster-yes
    depends_on:
      - redis-node-1
      - redis-node-2
      - redis-node-3
      - redis-node-4
      - redis-node-5
      - redis-node-6
```

Answer (score 0):

To begin with, note the following text from the [Redis documentation](https://redis.io/docs/management/scaling/#redis-cluster-and-docker):

> Currently, Redis Cluster does not support NATted environments and in general environments where IP addresses or TCP ports are remapped.
>
> Docker uses a technique called port mapping: programs running inside Docker containers may be exposed with a different port compared to the one the program believes to be using. This is useful for running multiple containers using the same ports, at the same time, in the same server.
>
> To make Docker compatible with Redis Cluster, you need to use Docker's host networking mode. Please see the --net=host option in the Docker documentation for more information.

If your goal is to expose the redis cluster outside of your compose environment, then you're going to need to run everything with `network_mode: host`. When running in host network mode, you cannot use port publishing, so you'll need to (a) get rid of the `ports` section in your services and (b) ensure that each instance is listening on a different port.

A second problem is that your `redis-cluster-creator` service runs before any of your redis containers are ready. The legacy form the `depends_on` option...

```
depends_on:
  - redis-node-1
  - redis-node-2
  - redis-node-3
  .
  .
  .
```

...is effectively useless; it only waits for the *container* to start; it doesn't know anything about the state of the application running inside the container. We can (a) add a healthcheck to the containers and then (b) use the [extended form of depends_on](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/05-services/#long-syntax-1) to wait until redis is actually up before attempting to create the cluster.

Lastly, a bunch of little things:

- You probably don't need an individual configuration file for each node; they should all be using identical configurations, other than the port, which can be set on the command line.
- You probably want to use persistent storage for the redis data directory in `/data`.

Putting all of that together, we get something like this:

```
services:
  redis-cluster-creator:
    command:
      - redis-cli
      - --cluster
      - create
      - localhost:7001
      - localhost:7002
      - localhost:7003
      - localhost:7004
      - localhost:7005
      - localhost:7006
      - --cluster-yes
      - --cluster-replicas
      - '1'
    depends_on:
      redis-node-1:
        condition: service_healthy
      redis-node-2:
        condition: service_healthy
      redis-node-3:
        condition: service_healthy
      redis-node-4:
        condition: service_healthy
      redis-node-5:
        condition: service_healthy
      redis-node-6:
        condition: service_healthy
    image: docker.io/redis:latest
    network_mode: host
  redis-node-1:
    command:
      - redis-server
      - /redis/redis.conf
      - --port
      - '7001'
    healthcheck:
      interval: 10s
      retries: '3'
      test:
        - CMD
        - redis-cli
        - -p
        - '7001'
        - -c
        - ping
      timeout: 5s
    image: docker.io/redis:latest
    network_mode: host
    ports:
      - 7001:7000
    volumes:
      - redis-data-1:/data
      - ./redis:/redis
  redis-node-2:
    command:
      - redis-server
      - /redis/redis.conf
      - --port
      - '7002'
    healthcheck:
      interval: 10s
      retries: '3'
      test:
        - CMD
        - redis-cli
        - -p
        - '7002'
        - -c
        - ping
      timeout: 5s
    image: docker.io/redis:latest
    network_mode: host
    ports:
      - 7002:7000
    volumes:
      - redis-data-2:/data
      - ./redis:/redis
  redis-node-3:
    command:
      - redis-server
      - /redis/redis.conf
      - --port
      - '7003'
    healthcheck:
      interval: 10s
      retries: '3'
      test:
        - CMD
        - redis-cli
        - -p
        - '7003'
        - -c
        - ping
      timeout: 5s
    image: docker.io/redis:latest
    network_mode: host
    ports:
      - 7003:7000
    volumes:
      - redis-data-3:/data
      - ./redis:/redis
  redis-node-4:
    command:
      - redis-server
      - /redis/redis.conf
      - --port
      - '7004'
    healthcheck:
      interval: 10s
      retries: '3'
      test:
        - CMD
        - redis-cli
        - -p
        - '7004'
        - -c
        - ping
      timeout: 5s
    image: docker.io/redis:latest
    network_mode: host
    ports:
      - 7004:7000
    volumes:
      - redis-data-4:/data
      - ./redis:/redis
  redis-node-5:
    command:
      - redis-server
      - /redis/redis.conf
      - --port
      - '7005'
    healthcheck:
      interval: 10s
      retries: '3'
      test:
        - CMD
        - redis-cli
        - -p
        - '7005'
        - -c
        - ping
      timeout: 5s
    image: docker.io/redis:latest
    network_mode: host
    ports:
      - 7005:7000
    volumes:
      - redis-data-5:/data
      - ./redis:/redis
  redis-node-6:
    command:
      - redis-server
      - /redis/redis.conf
      - --port
      - '7006'
    healthcheck:
      interval: 10s
      retries: '3'
      test:
        - CMD
        - redis-cli
        - -p
        - '7006'
        - -c
        - ping
      timeout: 5s
    image: docker.io/redis:latest
    network_mode: host
    ports:
      - 7006:7000
    volumes:
      - redis-data-6:/data
      - ./redis:/redis
volumes:
  redis-data-1: {}
  redis-data-2: {}
  redis-data-3: {}
  redis-data-4: {}
  redis-data-5: {}
  redis-data-6: {}
```

The contents of `redis/redis.conf` is:

```
cluster-enabled yes
cluster-config-file nodes.conf
cluster-node-timeout 5000
appendonly yes
```

You can see a successful `docker compose up` using this environment [here](https://asciinema.org/a/P1LZ7O6jOwHupjWOZvEn7t8PZ).

There is a lot of repetition in that compose file, so to make my life easier while experimenting I used [jsonnet](https://jsonnet.org/) to template things. You can find my complete environment at https://github.com/larsks/redis-cluster-example.